# What is the most effecient way to update multiple divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using html5 data attributes to store information about record and create a preview on hover.  I'm currently doing the code below but it gets a little sluggish at times.  It works, but I'm still learning and know this cant be the best way.

```
function showfileinfo() {
    var filetags = $(this).attr('data-filetags');
    var tags ='';

    if(filetags.length > 0) {
        $.each(filetags.split(','), function(index, item) {
            tags += '<div>' + item + '</div>';
        });
    }

    $('.tags').html('<div class="tag-image"><img src="/_ima/tag.png"/> tags</div>' + tags);
    $('#file-preview > h3:first').html($(this).attr('data-filetitle'));
    $('.file-name').html($(this).attr('data-filename') + ' - ' + humanize_filesize($(this).attr('data-filesize')));
    $('.description').html($(this).attr('data-filetext'));
    $('#file-preview').hide().fadeIn();

}
```

I'm updating this preview div.

```
<div id="file-preview" style="display:none;">
    <h3>Document Title</h3>
    <p class="file-name">acrobat.pdf - 4.06 MB</p>
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam aliquet arcu nec tortor porttitor laoreet sollicitudin odio vestibulum</p>
    <div class="tags">
        <div class="tag-image"><img src="/_ima/tag.png"/> tags</div>
        <div>wireframe</div>
        <div>visio</div>
        <div>workflow</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you change the DOM the browser needs to repaint the page. Which takes time. You should try to never change the DOM more than once (for every change that needs to happen, obviously if you do ajax requests or changes on user interaction you will need to change it again, but for each change you should only *change the DOM* once).

Also, simply adding element names to your selectors (`div.tags` rather than just `.tags`) would also speed things up, and if they're all located in the `#file-preview` element you should definitely select that first, and then just `find()` elements from there. That will also speed up *a lot*.

Comment: Also cache all selector results in variables so they aren't performed more often than necessary.

Comment: So the best thing I can do is just..
`var preview = $("#file-preview");  Then $(preview).find('.selector')`

Comment: That is better, yes. But also, specify the element name, not just the class. When you say `.class`, jQuery needs to check _every_ element for that class, if you say `div.class` it only needs to check divs.

Comment: @powerbuoy Not necessarily. Where supported, `.class` will use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), which is a fast, native method. Sometimes adding the tag name can actually slow it down. Weird, huh?

Comment: @rennacs If you have cached the results of a jQuery selector in a variable, it is a jQuery set/object. So there is no need to re-call the jQuery function using `$(myVar)`. Many people use a naming convention for such variables of starting with "$" to indicate variables which are already jQuery sets.

Comment: TBH I don't think getElementsByClassName is faster than getElementsByTagName, but I could be wrong. Regardless, I'm pretty sure jQuery uses querySelectorAll for almost everything. (Edit: except when selecting only an ID in which case I think it uses getElementByID)